# Unable to enter passphrase for LVM drive during boot

Tags: gnome, encryption, passphrase

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 and selected 'Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security" (and in turn selected the LVM option) during the initial installation. When I start up my computer I get a screen with the Gnome logo with an area asking for the passphrase I selected to encrypt the drive. I am unable to type anything into that spot. Pressing the Enter key also does nothing.

A temporarily solution I have discovered is to hold the left Shift key immediately when the computer starts and selecting the recovery option. I then select resume and it gives me a text version of the passphrase prompt which it accepts.

After reading through similar problems, it looks like it might not be loading the keyboard driver before it gives me the Gnome prompt but does when I go through the recovery mode. But I could be way off. I haven't selected any special keyboard just the stand 'US English' one.

Does anyone have any solutions?

Note: Running a MacBook Pro (2009, MacBook5,5).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Gnome, and can be easily fixed from recovery, as long as you are fine with Gnome being removed. Unity will still be there. Just boot into recovery, enable networking, and then drop to root shell. After you drop to shell do

`sudo apt-get purge gnome
 sudo apt-get update-grub && sudo apt-get upgrade
 sudo shutdown now -r`